# Реагирование JavaScript на изменение URL адреса

Tags: url, ajax, json, javascript

На странице `http://example.com/index.html` работает скрипт  `<script src="exaple.js"></script>`

Как сделать, чтобы этот скрипт загружался еще раз при изменении URL без перезагрузки?

Например, на странице `http://example.com/index.html#reload`.

Comment: http://example.com/index.html и http://example.com/index.html#reload это один и тот же URL, потому изменение URL не происходит. Опишите суть проблемы почетче.

Comment: Это та же самая страница но не тот же УРЛ  ..  адрес меняется а я хочу чтобы моя скрипт перезагружался при изменении УРЛА

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно поставить функцию, мониторящую URL с определенным интервалом и вызывающую нужные функции при его изменении.

Answer (score 1):

Ну раз адрес меняется, то происходит какое-то событие, соответственно проще всего, я думаю, привязать к этому событию так же загрузку необходимых скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Можно при измненении урла подгружать js-скрипт.

Comment: Мысль хорошая, но я пиши для клиентских страниц и манипулировать ссылками не могу

Answer (score 0):

м.б. есть смысл не отслеживать url, а просто написать обработчики для этих ссылок? обозначить их нужными id и реагировать на их нажатие(`<a href="http://example.com/index.html" id="somelink">somelink</a>`). url всегда будет один и тот же, за то через обработчик клику по id вы сможете отправить ajax запрос и получить необходимый контент. Это как вариант можно рассмотреть. Если все таки изменять url по клику через href, то тогда есть смысл посмотреть в сторону location.href, парсить url и выполнять действия. но опять же, необходимо писать функцию на js, которая будет отслеживать клики по ссылке, парсить урл и загружать ваш скрипт(хотя наверное не загружать, он то уже загружен, а запускать какую то функцию, которую он содержит).
Напишите подробнее ситуацию как это все должно работать в вашем понимании.